# XHR progress event not firing until upload completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm using the following $.ajax command to upload a file from a PhoneGap application:

```
function updateProgress( evt ) {
    if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
        console.log( percentComplete + "%" );
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false, 
    success: successCallback,
    error: errorCallback,
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener( "progress", updateProgress, false);
        return xhr;
    }
});
```

The upload works fine.  However the progress event only fires one time, once the upload has completed.  It does not actually fire during uploading - so upload progress does not actually display.  There is just a pause while it is uploading, and then it displays 100%.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the size of file?

Comment: Have you tried: `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);` ?

Comment: Filesize is a couple of megabytes - big enough that it takes more than 1/2 a second to upload.  Adding the event listener to xhr.upload causes nothing to fire at all, even on complete.  Thanks!

Comment: Having the exact same problem.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @A.Wolff I have been stuck with this problem quire a lot time today!  This is so right! Thank you!! but according to the doc, why `xhr.addEventListener` do not work ?

Answer (score 35):

The upload `progress` events are fired on `xhr.upload`, so attach the listener to that rather than `xhr`. There are also `progress` events on the `xhr` object but this is for the response coming back from the server.

See [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) for more details.

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false)
```

<sub><sup>(Thanks to A. Wolff and his comment on the OP.)</sup></sub>